# Athena and CloudTrail - Bucketing on ['account','year','month','day'] (no region)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail

I am just getting started with Athena with the intent of querying CloudTrail management events from multiple accounts.

**I am configuring the first table following this guide:**

https://cloudonaut.io/analyzing-cloudtrail-with-athena/

Due to the folder structure (key prefix) of the CloudTrail events it is partitioned by:

```
PARTITIONED BY (account string, region string, year string, month string, day, string)
```

**I am then creating another table with CATS to convert the JSON to ORC and store in another bucket following this guide:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-ctas-statements-with-amazon-athena-to-reduce-cost-and-improve-performance/

My lack of knowledge with databases is likely making me overly greedy.  I would like to skip over region when setting up the bucket partitions.  I cannot think of a reason I would want to query only one specific region per account for management events and do not want thirty files per account per day if I could have three.

**This is what I am trying to run:**

```
CREATE TABLE cloudtrail_partitioned_bucketed
WITH (
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['account','year','month','day'],
  bucketed_by = ARRAY['eventname'],
  bucket_count = 3,
  format = 'orc',
  external_location = 's3://bucket/athena/out/'
)
AS
SELECT
  *
FROM cloudtrail_logs
```

**I get the error:**

```
HIVE_COLUMN_ORDER_MISMATCH: Partition keys must be the last columns in the table and in the same order as the table properties
```

Sure enough if I just use the values in order regardless of which values it works (account,region / year,month,day).  I understand the partition keys are not dynamic, but **can I just drop the partition key "region" for the orc conversion?**  I have awsregion from the events themselves.

**Any feedback regarding how bad of an idea this is would be welcome.**  The concept I have in my head is to have something scheduled to run once a day converting the days CloudTrail events in each account to ORC in a different bucket for use with Athena queries.  The CloudTrail events will be archived sooner and all queries run by users with Athena will run against the smaller ORC files.

Given the number of accounts I would like to decrease the number of partitions necessary when using region in the partition keys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am a bit dense.  I came back after a break and tried everything again.  This time I did not make the assumption the initial table creation keys had anything to do with the folder path.

instead of:

```
PARTITIONED BY (account string, region string, year string, month string, day, string)
```

I used:

```
PARTITIONED BY (account string, year string, month string, day, string)
```

and it appears to work.

I still do not know if what I am doing is logical.  Any input in that regard would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your original question uses `CREATE TABLE ... AS`, while your answer appears to show a standard `CREATE TABLE` statement. If you use CTAS, you need to be explicit abut the columns selected from the source (ie, no `SELECT *`).

Comment: Also, does it make sense to bucket by event name? In my experience, that field tends to be very skewed, with a few names for the majority of events (eg, in a lambda-centric deployment, assume role and create log stream tend to dominate).

Comment: Thank you.  I realized how dumb my first question was but did not want to take it down incase someone like me had the same issue.  My reasoning the path was also related to the keys rather than me literally defining what the keys are and giving the path.

regarding explicit columns on CTAS I had no idea.  I am just stumbling through what I can find with Google and it does not cover the basics much.

Regarding the event name I found this odd to.  There are things like that and the ORC instead of Parquet that I am not sure of.  I trusted the AWS blog to know better than me. Thank you!